# stop Desire2Learn from resetting SCORM runtime data on new attempts

Tags: desire2learn, scorm2004

I am fairly new to SCORM and am currently tasked to track user score in a e-learning course-ware. What needs to happen is that the scores will only be capture if it is higher than the previous attempt. For example, I scored 50 in my 1st attempt, and in my 2nd attempt, my score will only be capture if it is higher than 50.

However, I noticed that D2L resets the courseware's runtime data on every new attempt. This causes the score to reset to 0 when I retry the course.
I have tried running the course-ware on SCORM Cloud and it works perfectly when the "Reset Runtime Data" option is disabled.

Does D2L has a similar function to stop resetting runtime data? Or is there a way to over come this?

Answer (score 0):

If your course's `cmi.exit` is set to `normal`, by spec, SCORM will treat the next launch as a new attempt, with a fresh score. If you set `cmi.exit` to `suspend`, the next launch will resume the prior session, with prior score intact. Note some LMSs may not allow you to update the score after setting the course status to `completed`.

SCORM does not provide a way to selectively replace a previous score with a new one (such as "only take the new score if it's higher"). This would be a function of the admin controls within the LMS, and not all LMSs will provide the function.

I don't have experience with the D2L LMS, so I can't speak to it. Since the question is really about admin functionality in D2L, and not SCORM programming, I suggest you post your question in the D2L support forums. Good luck.

Comment: Thanks pipwerks. I have contacted D2L support and should be hearing from them soon.